# Can I use Google sign-in in my Android app in NavigationView Items?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wonder whether it is possible to use a NavigationView item to implement Google sign-in because always using a Sign-in button seems to be pretty restrictive on where I can put the sign-in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to make custom `NavigationView` for that